# Powershell script to retrieve the same kind of info reported by DMDIAG for dynamic disks

Tags: powershell, wmi, partition

[This article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2011/09/26/alignment-changes-in-windows-2008-and-2008-r2.aspx) about windows partition alignment explains that checking the alignment offset of dynamic disks can be done with the DMDIAG tool to get the "relative sectors" property.

With dynamic disks the StartingOffset property, reported by the win32_DiskParition wmi class, can be deceiving (as explained in the article).

Is there a wmi class that provides this "relative sectors" info or is there a way to calculate it manually with the info wmi does provide?

Comment: Where is the article?

Comment: The text "This article" is what we call a "hyperlink", clicking on it will direct your web browser to the url embedded in the html "anchor". Are you the one that down voted me because of your unfamiliarity with the arcane, technological obscurity that is the hyperlink? If so it would be nice of you to fix that. Thanks.